# QT translate text to a specific locale

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there a way to translate some text to a specific locale (not the current system locale)? I would like to achieve something like this:

```
QString QObject::tr(const char * sourceText, const QLocale& locale);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [QTranslator::translate()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#translate) can do that. You just need to load the correct translation catalog with the specific language first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qt Linguist for translations. Just use the following [tutorial](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2017/01/04/translating-qml-app/)